# inexpensive bike for Wahoo Kickr

Tags: wahoo

I bought a Wahoo Kickr trainer in 2020 and have been using it almost daily with my Trek Madone 4.5. But I also ride the bike 3x times per week and I am getting tired of taking the rear tire on and off to mount it on the trainer. So I thought I could get a cheep second bike and just leave it on the trainer permanently. First I thought I would find a used bike in my size (60 cm), but the few that I saw were either very old, or too expensive for what I want the bike for. Does anyone have a recommendation for a cheep department store (Walmart/Amazon) bike that would be compatible with the Wahoo trainer? I think that I can get something with a 7 speed Shimano cassette and mount that on the Kickr with a spacer?

Comment: Sorry we don't really do shopping questions like this - they're considered off topic because of limited long term use.

Comment: Any old shitter will do. Think less, pedal more 

Answer (score 1):

Any bike should work on your trainer, as long as the rear axle mounts up the same way, probably a QR skewer.

Ideally the trainer-bike would duplicate your existing bike fit, so have the same stack and reach and similar saddle and handlebars.

You're right, any size cassette will work in terms of gearing, but it may be worth having at least the same number of rear cogs and about the same intervals as your road bike for muscle memory.
 That way you don't need to have spare 10 speed and 7 speed chain and so on.
 Likewise it would be good if the rear wheel was about the same width as your existing bike, to "use up" the tail-end of the tread in your road bike tyres.

Ideally the trainer bike would have the same kind of pedals as your road bike, and similar crank arm lengths and Q factors.

Good luck with searching locally for a suitable second bike.

Comment: The Kickr (even in 2020) came with various endcaps for 135 mm QR axles, 10 x 142 mm thru axles, and10 x 148 mm thru axles. I bet you coulkd buy superboost end caps too.

Comment: @PaulH good point - that's worth being an answer of its own.   OP might only have caps to suit one kind of rear axle, which could limit the kind of bikes that can be used.

Comment: “Likewise it would be good if the rear wheel was about the same width as your existing bike, to "use up" the tail-end of the tread in your road bike tyres.” I think OP has a direct drive trainer i.e. the chain directly connects to a cassette mounted on the trainer and not with the rear wheel pressed against a drum.

Comment: A 2020 Kickr (Vx or Core) must be direct drive, the Rollr (well...) and Snap (wheel-on) were introduced way later. Depending on your indoor riding, gearing might not even matter so much - you can reduce trainer difficulty so that the Alpè is ridable with a 25t cassette and when you mostly do workouts, just choose the cog you want to wear down this season and never shift the rear for the next 4 months like I do...^^